# SQL Server use column value as column names and convert to json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, pivot

Let's say I have the following table ProductValues:

| ProductID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Market | A |
| 1 | Customer | B |
| 2 | Market | C |
| 2 | Customer | D |

I'm able to group them by their ProductID and get these values as an array with the following code:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT Name, Value FROM ProductValues
    WHERE P.ID = ProductID
    FOR JSON PATH
)
FROM @ProductIDs P '@ProductIDs is a table containing the productIDs that Id like to retrieve'
```

This returns the following:

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| [{"Name":"Market","Value":"A"},{"Name":"Customer","Value":"B"}] |
| [{"Name":"Market","Value":"C"},{"Name":"Customer","Value":"D"}] |

I would like to dynamically create key value pairs using Pivot. I want to achieve the following:

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| [{"Market":"A"},{"Customer":"B"}] |
| [{"Market":"C"},{"Customer":"D"}] |

Looking at another answer, I tried the following, but this doesn't set the keys dynamically and won't execute (states that "Value" and "TechName" in the Pivot are undefined):

```
SELECT(
    SELECT Market, Customer
    FOR JSON PATH
)
FROM(
    SELECT(
        SELECT Name, Value FROM ProductValues
        WHERE ProductID =  P.ID
    )
    FROM @ProductIDs P
) t
PIVOT(
    MAX(Value)  '<--- "Value" Undefined'
    FOR Name IN ( '<--- "Name" Undefined'
        Market, Customer
    )
) AS pvt
GROUP BY
    Market, Customer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation, the convert to JSON:

```
select (
    select
        max(case when name = 'Market'   then value end) as market,
        max(case when name = 'Customer' then value end) as customer
    from productvalues pv
    where pv.productid = p.productid
    for json path
) as js
from @ProductIDs p
```

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e9aede055d5555ce74a5f40f5437f28)**.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is declarative by design.  If you are looking for dynamic columns, you will need **DYNAMIC SQL**.

**Example**

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max) = stuff( (Select Distinct ','+QUOTENAME(Name) From ProductValues FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 

SET @sql = 'Select B.*
              From (
                    SELECT '+@sql+'
                    FROM  ProductValues 
                    PIVOT (max([Value]) FOR [Name] IN ('+@sql+')) AS pvt
                   ) A
             Cross Apply ( (Select A.* for json path ) ) B (JSONData)'
exec(@sql)
```

**Returns**

```
JSONData
[{"Customer":"B","Market":"A"}]
[{"Customer":"D","Market":"C"}]
```